# How to change an icon for one single file of the specific type?

Tags: c#, windows, shell, file, icons

I know how to change an icon for a whole file type using registry and file type association.
I also know how to change an icon for a separate folder using desktop.ini file.

My questions is whether it is possible to **change an icon for one specific file**, let's say one.doc file?

I cannot find a way doing it, yet some upload programs seem to be able to change an icon of the currently uploaded file, while all other files of this type stay with the standard icon. How do they do it?

I can accept a solution in any language; VB, C++, C# - anything goes, though C# is preferable.
Thanks

Comment: You just want to change it from the default icon on one document?

Comment: Are you on a mac or windows? I assume windows...

Comment: I feel like I don't understand the question entirely... you want to do it in C# but why not just change it from windows? http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/icons.htm

Comment: @Charlie - because if you change an icon from Windows, it will change it for the whole type, while I want to do it for one specific file of that type, let's say one Word document. Creating a shortcut isn't a solution, as I want to change the icon of the original file.

Comment: You probably misinterpret what an "upload program" does.  They commonly use a different filename extension while the upload takes place.  Renaming it when it completes.  The icon automatically changes as a side-effect.

Comment: @Hans Passant - I just found a couple of secs ago that they do it using Icon Overlay Handlers. I never heard about them before, I am reading this article now:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects

Comment: I know on a Mac you can change individual icons per file/folder. There's no way to do this on windows?

Comment: @Flot2011 - Have you found any solution to this problem? I have exactly same requirement.

Comment: @deepak - yes, I did, it is an [Overlay Icon Handler Shall Extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects)

Comment: @Flot2011 -  Thanks for reply. Could you tell me how to consume that code? I mean how to use that code?

Comment: [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/ATLShellExtIconOverlayHandl-4b6b79e5) you can find the working sample for this technique with a very detailed documentation and heavily commented code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [IconHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to allow icons to be customized on a file-by-file basis. Note that [shell extensions should not be written in managed code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so C++ is the language of choice here.

Note also that it's highly unusual to be installing an icon handler for another application's file type.

Comment: actually I was looking for a way to change an original icon, something that Tortoise does, for example. I have already figured out that Icon Overlay Handler should be used for this, however your post turned me in another direction. One can have only up to 14 Icon Overlay Handlers simultaneously, while a number of  Icon Handlers seems to be unlimited, so probably it is a better course to take. Thank you.

Comment: However, there can be only one Icon Handler per file type, so installing an Icon Handler should really be done only by the owner of the file type. Otherwise you have the "What if two people did this?" problem.

Answer (score 3):

I realize that this thread is pretty old. But for users who have less experience in coding, a good alternative is the following.

1. Put your target file somewhere.
2. Create a shortcut item to that file.
3. Now you can change the icon of the shortcut using its property window.

Just another solution. More of a workaround really.

Comment: The issue with what you say is how do you do that programmatically, because a link created with mklink for instance won't be customizable like a link created with a right click.

Answer (score -1):

If you create a SHORTCUT file to that file, then simply RIGHT click on that SHORTCUT, you get the options to change the ICON.

Comment: This is the same suggestion that @Lost-in-Knowledge gave a couple of years ago.