# Is it possible to change the icon of one specific file with Java?

Tags: java, windows, icons

I was reading up on 
[How to change an icon for one single file of the specific type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046903/how-to-change-an-icon-for-one-single-file-of-the-specific-type)
 but I was wondering if this is possible with Java? I know how to change the icon of a whole file type but I'm not sure how to, or if its possible to, change the icon of one specific file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Icon to JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657569/how-to-set-icon-to-jframe)

Comment: @ron190 No, not this question. OP does not want to change the icon of the application but the icon rendered for a specific file-type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setIconImage:

```
frame.setIconImage(
new imageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image.png")));
```

Also check out [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Im asking about **other** applications, not just the one being ran. For example changing the icon of **a single** .doc